# How to include the package in local directory in to the main.go

Tags: go

I am using go version go1.11.2 windows/amd64 in windows 10

i have folder in desktop with name "GoPro" which has 
one file - main.go
one folder - Modules

The "Modules" folder contains 
one file - Modules.go

Folder Structure

```
Desktop
   |------->GoPro
               |----->main.go
               |----->Models
                          |---->Models.go
```

main.go

```
// desktop/GoPro/main.go 

package main

import (
    "./Models"
)

func main() {
    Models.Printhello()
}
```

Models.go

```
// desktop/GoPro/Models

package Models

import "fmt"

func Printhello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

If try to run the main.go , I am getting the below error , Go recongise the package but it saying undefined.

> go run main.go
>
> ## command-line-arguments
>
> .\main.go:8:2: undefined: Models

The folder is not in GOPATH. I am just trying to import the package with in sub folder of main.go

Comment: Please read How to Write Go Code. You do not import files but packages and probably your package is not called "Models". Also: Do not use relative imports as this is a stupid idea.

Comment: Is there perhaps a duplicate that explains **why** relative imports are a bad idea?

Comment: @Volker Why relative imports are stupid idea. In many website I  saw , people are saying not to use relative imports. I am just trying to port my codes form Python to Go, In python all my additional packages are imported relative path. To maintain the same structure I am trying to import packages in  relative path.

Comment: Relative imports do not play well along all the tooling. Using full qualified import paths is _dead_ _simple_ and will result in a project structure which works well. Spending 5 minutes to convert to full import paths is much less work than wasting hours fiddling with relative imports. Relative imports turned out to be a stupid idea and using them will result in needless problems. You can still maintain the same file system structure, all you need to do is use non-relative import paths. It really is  that simple. And please: Decapitalise the model name!!

Comment: @Volker. Thanks. hereafter I will follow the standard ways

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go)

Answer (score 1):

You can either [set up](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH) `$GOPATH` and place your library in a path relative to `$GOPATH`, or [use modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

For modules, you can do something like:

```
$ tree
.
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── mylib
    └── mylib.go
```

Contents of files:

```
$ cat go.mod
module myproject.com

====

$ cat main.go 
package main

import "myproject.com/mylib"

func main() {
    mylib.Say()
}

====

$ cat mylib/mylib.go 
package mylib

import "fmt"

func Say() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from mylib")
}
```

P.S. use lowercase to [name packages/modules](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names)