# How correctly to run golang application in docker?

Tags: docker, go

I developed Golang application in Windows 10. In my local machine it works fine. I remove source code to remote CentOS server which has Docker. Right now I am trying to run this application in Docker.

I created **Dockerfile** in the same folder where located **main.go** file.

```
- questionnaire
    - database
    - routes
    - utils
    - models
    - controllers
      main.go
      Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile** looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.12

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && \
  go get github.com/gorilla/handlers && \
  go get github.com/lib/pq && \
  go get github.com/joho/godotenv && \
  go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm && \
  go get github.com/go-goracle/goracle

COPY / ./

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

My **main.go** file looks pretty simple:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "github.com/joho/godotenv"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "questionnaire/database"
  "questionnaire/routes"
  "questionnaire/utils"
)

func main()  {
  err := godotenv.Load(".env")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  database.ConnectOracle()
  defer database.DisconnectOracle()

  router := mux.NewRouter()

  headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
  methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})
  origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})

  router.StrictSlash(true)

  routes.Handle(router)

  port := utils.CheckEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATION_PORT")

  log.Printf("RESTful web service is running on %s port.", port)

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + port, handlers.CORS(headers, methods, origins)(router)))
}
```

I successfully created Docker Image but I have error when created Docker Container:

```
main.go:9:2: cannot find package "questionnaire/database" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/questionnaire/database (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/questionnaire/database (from $GOPATH)
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "questionnaire/routes" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/questionnaire/routes (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/questionnaire/routes (from $GOPATH)
main.go:11:2: cannot find package "questionnaire/utils" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/questionnaire/utils (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/questionnaire/utils (from $GOPATH)
```

Can anyone say how to fix this problem?

I also tried to build binary of golang application inside Docker by next Dockerfile but error message was the same `RUN go build` command:

```
FROM golang:1.12

RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && \
  go get github.com/gorilla/handlers && \
  go get github.com/lib/pq && \
  go get github.com/joho/godotenv && \
  go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm && \
  go get gopkg.in/goracle.v2

ADD . /go/src/questionnaire

WORKDIR /go/src/questionnaire

RUN go build -o /bin questionnaire

ENV PORT=8000

CMD ["/bin"]
```

Comment: Don't use relative imports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go)

Comment: @Flimzy hello! Why you think this post is duplicate? It is different question ;(

Comment: This line: `RUN go build -o /bin questionnaire` doesn't seem like a good idea to me, most if not all linuxes have a folder called `bin` at the root of the filesystem. That folder contains a bunch of binaries that are probably required for the machine to run as expected. By overwriting that folder with your app's binary, you are setting yourself up for some headaches, I think... I haven't tried it so I can't say for sure... either way I would recommend you rename your binary to something that doesn't conflict with existing files/folders or...

Comment: ... keep the name but move it into a subfolder where that name is not yet taken.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek: Because the problem you're having is explained in that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imports in your `main.go` file specify:

`"questionnaire/database"
  "questionnaire/routes"
  "questionnaire/utils"`

This means the go compiler is looking for those packages in `$GOPATH/questionnaire` and `$GOROOT/questionnaire`. You have to make sure those are copied into the correct place inside the docker image you are building.

The default $GOPATH inside that `golang:1.12` image is `/go`. Make sure your questionnaire package is correctly placed in the `/go/src` directory inside the docker image.

As for the Dockerfile:
A common strategy when building / deploying Docker images for go apps is to use a builder pattern (see example Dockerfile below). The gist of it is to create a multi-stage Dockerfile, where the first stage builds the go executable, and the second stage runs it. This means you can isolate all of your dependencies in the first stage, and end up with a very small overall image at the end.

It might look something like this:

```
FROM golang:1.11-alpine AS builder

########
# Prep
########

# add the source
COPY . /go/src/questionnaire
WORKDIR /go/src/questionnaire/

########
# Build Go Wrapper
########

# Install go dependencies
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux && \
  go get github.com/gorilla/handlers && \
  go get github.com/lib/pq && \
  go get github.com/joho/godotenv && \
  go get github.com/jinzhu/gorm && \
  go get github.com/go-goracle/goracle

#build the go app
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o ./questionnaire ./main.go

########
# Package into runtime image
########
FROM alpine

# copy the executable from the builder image
COPY --from=builder /go/src/questionnaire .

ENTRYPOINT ["/questionnaire"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Hope this helps!

(edited to reflect the comments below)

Comment: *"It looks lik database, routes, and utils are files in the same folder as your main.go."* They are not files, they are folders. And they are also valid packages since, as OP stated in the first paragraph, the app works fine on their local machine. If those were files the app would not be able to compile with those imports.

Comment: mkopriva is right! `database`, `routes`, and `utils` are folders (packages). Inside them I have different `.go` files. As I can see you use multi-stage builds. In fact I use `Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2`. Multi-stage builds is not aviable in that version.

Comment: My mistake!
I definitely misread that.

I've updated my response accordingly.

The folder and package structure of your app looks fine - I suspect the questionnaire package just wasn't being added to the `GOPATH` within the docker image.

Comment: As for the multi-stage build, you can ignore it if your version doesn't support it - I think making sure the files are added to the $GOPATH should resolve your issue.