# How to avoid package dependency

Tags: go

I have a project consisting of 4 parts:

1. A gateway (gateway/gateway.go) it's a package that knows how to talk with an application server and open this connection channel.
2. A runner (runner/runner.go) it's the main (go build -o runner/runner runner/runner.go) It loads and execute Modules (using reflect I run functions from the module)!
3. A framework (framework/framework.go) Implements many functionalities calling the gateway.
4. Modules (aka Plugins in Go) (modules/sample.go) (go build -buildmode plugin -o modules/sample.so ./modules/sample.go) Using the framework, does customer logic! When init I export the reflect.Value of struct, then runner can run methods of this struct.

I want the runner instantiate the gateway and the framework obtain this instance without create a dependency between runner/framework.

Why? To avoid Go error 'plugin was built with a different version of package' when runner loads the module! 
If I update the runner (with the framework changed), I will invalidate old modules.

I already do that using 2 ways I don't like:

1. Using context, but all functions from module and framework need receive a parameter context, then framework extract the gateway.
2. Just let the framework instantiate gateway, but then the runner cannot use gateway.

Comment: have the gateway package keep the instance initialized by runner

Comment: I would strongly recommend against this design. This is the kind of runtime dynamic stuff that Ruby and Java love, but which goes against the grain of everything that Go is built on.

Comment: I could not agree more with @Adrian. The "modules" should be various "main", configuring "framework" to utilize "gateway" and "runner", not the other way around.

Comment: The "runner" will be executed by the application server (fork), loads one "module", execute and finish

Comment: This is a terrible design. Please don't do things this way.

Comment: Why is so terrible? Because use plugin? Because reflect with plugin? Yes, Go is not the best language for this dynamic stuff, but I cannot use other language

Comment: Don't do "dynamic stuff".

Answer (score -1):

There have been a lot of headaches with Go plugins, especially the plugin compiler version must exactly match the program's compiler version. But the example works.

***runner/runner.go***

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "plugin"
  "reflect"

  "../gateway"
  "../dep"
)

var a *gateway.Gateway

func main() {
  myModule := os.Args[1]

  if _, err := plugin.Open(myModule); err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  mod, err := dep.NewModule()
  if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  a = gateway.NewGW()
  ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "gateway", a)

  modreflect, err := mod.Init(ctx, dep.Config{})
  if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  if !modreflect.IsValid() {
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  modnode, err := mod.Start(ctx)
  if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1002)
  }

  for {
    if len(modnode) <= 0 {
      break
    }

    modnoderefl := modreflect.MethodByName(modnode)
    if !modnoderefl.IsValid() {
      break
    }

    result := modnoderefl.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(ctx)})
    if len(result) != 2 {
      break
    }

    modnode = result[0].String()
  }

  mod.End(ctx)
}
```

***gateway/gateway.go***

```
package gateway

type Gateway struct {}

fun NewGW() *Gateway {
  a := Gateway{}
  return &a
}
```

***dep/dep.go***

```
package dep

import (
  "errors"
  "context"
  "reflect"
)

// Config is a configuration provider.
type Config map[string]interface{}

// Module is the interface implementated by types that
// register themselves as modular plug-ins.
type Module interface {
  Init(ctx context.Context, config Config) (reflect.Value,error)
  Start(ctx context.Context) (string,error)
  End(ctx context.Context) error
}

var themod = []func() Module{}

func RegisterModule(ctor func() Module) {
  themod = append(themod, ctor)
}

func NewModule() (Module, error) {
  if len(themod) == 0 {
    return nil, errors.New("Module not registered")
  }
  return themod[0](), nil
}
```

***framework/framework.go***

```
package framework

import (
    "fmt"
  "context"
  "../gateway"
)

type PlayFileInput struct {
  Path string
}

func Play(ctx context.Context, p PlayFileInput) error {
  if a := ctx.Value("gateway"); a != nil {

    if a.(*gateway.Gateway) != nil {
      _, err := a.(*gateway.Gateway).Exec("Playback", p.Path)
      return err
    }
  }

  return nil
}
```

***modules/sample.go***

```
package main

import "C"

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
  "reflect"

  "../dep"
  "../framework"
)

type MyModuleImpl struct {}

func init() {
  dep.RegisterModule(func() dep.Module {
    return &MyModuleImpl{}
  })
}

func (m *MyModuleImpl) Init(ctx context.Context, config dep.Config) (reflect.Value, error) {
  return reflect.ValueOf(m), nil
}

func (m *MyModuleImpl) Start(ctx context.Context) (string,error) {
  return "Menu_1",nil
}
func (n *MyModuleImpl)Menu_1(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
  framework.Play(ctx, framework.PlayFileInput{Path: "welcome.wav"})
  return "Menu_2",nil
}
func (n *MyModuleImpl)Menu_2(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
  return "Menu_3", nil
}
// ....
// ....
func (m *MyModuleImpl) End(ctx context.Context) error {
  return nil
}
```

Comment: ` "../gateway"` <-- don't use relative imports. It's officially unsupported, and only works "kind of by accident".See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38517593/13860

Comment: Your entire project looks like you're trying to fight against Go. You're using reflection, you're forcing plugins, you're using incorrect imports. I strongly encourage you to start fresh, read a book about Go idioms, and take a new approach.