# Is it possible to call a test Func from another file to start the testing

Tags: go

Is it possible to call a test Function from a non test go file to start the execution of tests?

e.g., I have a test function:

```
package API

import "testing"

func TestAPI(t *testing.T) { 
...
}
```

I need to call this from a non test go file.

```
package main

import "../API"

API.TestAPI()
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Please [don't use relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38517593/13860)

Answer (score 7):

There are some great testing patterns in Go. Unfortunately, the way that you're trying to test is not going to work.

Your unit tests should be run using the command `go test <pkg`. Tests should never be called from within your code itself.

Generally there are two main forms of unit testing in Go - black and white box unit testing.

> White-box testing: Testing **unexported** functions from within the
>   package itself.
>
> Black-box testing: Testing **exported** functions from outside the
>   package, emulating how other packages will interact with it.

If I have a package, `example`, that I'd like to test. There is a simple **exported** function that sums a list of numbers that are provided. There is also an **unexported** utility function that's used by the `Sum` function.

**example.go**

```
package example

func Sum(nums ...int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, num := range nums {
        sum = add(sum, num)
    }
    return sum
}

func add(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

**example_test.go** : black-box testing

Notice that I'm testing the `example` package, but the test sits in the `example_test` package. Adding the `_test` keeps the Go compiler happy and lets it know that this is a testing package for `example`. Here, we may only access exported variables and functions which lets us test the behaviour that external packages will experience when importing and using our `example` package.

```
package example_test

import (
    "testing"

    "example"
)

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        nums []int
        sum  int
    }{
        {nums: []int{1, 2, 3}, sum: 6},
        {nums: []int{2, 3, 4}, sum: 9},
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        s := example.Sum(test.nums...)
        if s != test.sum {
            t.FailNow()
        }
    }
}
```

**example_internal_test.go** : white-box testing

Notice that I'm testing the `example` package, and the test also sits in the `example` package. This allows the unit tests to access unexported variables and functions.

```
package example

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        a   int
        b   int
        sum int
    }{
        {a: 1, b: 2, sum: 3},
        {a: 3, b: 4, sum: 7},
    }

    for _, test := range tests {
        s := add(test.a, test.b)
        if s != test.sum {
            t.FailNow()
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this you a better understanding on how Go's testing framework is set up and should be used. I haven't used any external libraries in the examples for simplicity sake, although a very popular and powerful package to help with unit testing is [github.com/stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify).

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting *is* possible, but not advised, as it depends on internal details of Go's `testing` library, which are not covered by the Go 1 Compatibly Guarantee, meaning you'll likely have to tweak this approach for every version of Go.

You should rarely, if ever, attempt this.  I did this once, for a suite of API integration tests that I wanted to be able to run as normal tests, but also from a CLI tool, to test third-party implementations of the API. Now that I've done it, I'm not sure I'd do it again. I'd probably look for a different approach.

But if you can't be dissuaded, here's what you need to do:

1. Your tests must *not* be defined in a file named `*_test.go`. Such files are excluded from normal compilation.
2. You must trigger the tests to run from a file appropriately named `*_test.go`, for your normal test case.
3. You must manually orchestrate the tests in your non-test case.

In detail:

1. Put tests in non-test files.  The `testing` package is just a standard package, so it's easy to include wherever you need it:

   **foo.go**

   ```golang
   package foo

   import "testing"

   func SomethingTest(t *testing.T) {
     // your tests
   }
   ```
2. Run the tests from a `*_test.go` file:

   **foo_test.go**

   ```golang
   func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
       SomethingTest(t)
   }
   ```
3. And run the tests from your non-test files. Here you are in risky territory, as it requires using methods that are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guarantee. You need to call the [testing.MainStart](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#MainStart) method, with a manually-crafted list of tests.

   This also requires implementing your own version of `testing.testDeps`, which is private, but an interface, so easy to implement. You can see my Go 1.9 implementation [here](https://github.com/go-kivik/kiviktest/blob/master/go19testing.go).

   ```golang
   tests := []testing.InternalTest{
       {
           Name: "TestSomething",
           f:     SomethingTest,
       },
   }
   m := testing.MainStart(MyTestDeps, tests, nil, nil)
   os.Exit(m.Run())
   ```

This is a very simplified example, not meant to be complete. But I hope it puts you on the right path.