# Relative import in Go for protobuf , cannot find module path

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, go-modules, grpc-go

I'm trying to write a service in go with gRPC, and when i import the protobuff file , getting an error. i tried removing all the modules in my go path and reinitialising the go modules

```
build _/Users/tibinlukose/cart-service/pb: cannot find module for path _/Users/tibinlukose/cart-service/pb
```

Code

```
package main

import (
    pbcart "../pb/"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "net"
)

var (
    port = 1000;
)

type CartServiceServer struct {
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    fmt.Println("Server Starting ..")
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", 10000))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("unable to listen on the port")
    }
    serverOptions := []grpc.ServerOption{}
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(serverOptions...)
    srv := &CartServiceServer{}
    pbcart.RegisterCartServiceServer(grpcServer, srv)
}
```

env

```
GOCACHE="/Users/tibinlukose/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/tibinlukose/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOPATH="/Users/tibinlukose/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.4/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.4/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOMOD="/Users/tibinlukose/cart-service/server/go.mod"
```

repo https://github.com/zycon/cart-service

Comment: [Don't use relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `go.mod` to the root and update import to `github.com/zycon/cart-service/pb`?

There is no relative import in Go. You can see this answer for an extended explanation: [Relative imports in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go)

There is a proposal: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20883

Comment: Kewl, it woks , could you give some info where i went wrong, @Flimzy mentioned not use relative imports.