# How to call a method in Golang from a different package

Tags: go

my errors.go file

```
 package errors

import (
    "net/http"
)

type RestError struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Status  int    `json:"status"`
    Error   string `json:"error"`
}

func (err *RestError) NewBadRequestError(message string) {
    err.Message = message
    err.Status = http.StatusBadRequest
    err.Error = "bad_request"
}
```

my user.go file

```
 package users

import (
    errors "Utils/Errors"
)

type (
    User struct {
        ID       uint   `json:"id"`
        Name     string `json:"name"`
        LastName string `json:"last_name"`
        Email    string `json:"email"`
    }
)

func (u *User) Validate() (err *errors.RestError) {

    if u.Name == "" {
        return &err.NewBadRequestError("The name field can't be empty")
    }

    return nil
}
```

i always get the following compiler error

```
err.NewBadRequestError(*message) (no value) used as valuecompiler
```

Would like to know what i'm doing wrong.
 I also tried return &err.NewBadRequestError(message: "The name field can't be empty")
but still get the following syntax error :
missing ',' in argument listsyntax

Comment: This isn't causing your immediate problem, but `import ( errors "Utils/Errors" )` is invalid. [Go does not support relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go).

Comment: Looks like you have a typo? you meant to do &erros.NewBadRequestError("The name field can't be empty") ?   ---  err => errors
@Gaetan Sobze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with separate packages.

First, `err` isn't defined. I'm assuming you have it defined somewhere not shown in the code you pasted.  If this is accurate...

```
return &err.NewBadRequestError("The name field can't be empty")
```

Doesn't make any sense.

First, `err.NewBadRequestError()` doesn't return anything, so there is nothing to return.

Second, you've have a `&`, which means to take the address of the value, but once again, there's no value--this is what the error is telling you.

It's not clear what your code is meant to do, so I can't tell you exactly how to fix it.  One option is just to remove `return &` from your code:

```
    if u.Name == "" {
        err.NewBadRequestError("The name field can't be empty")
    }
```

Another would be to modify `NewBadRequestError` to return some value.

Comment: The error.go file is a custom error handling file.
When i have a bad request, i return a NewBadRest func that receive the RestErr struct.
if u.Name == "" {
        err.NewBadRequestError("The name field can't be empty")
    } means if i have an empty name, i return a badrequest response custom error