# Compilation error only building a module, not main package

Tags: go, module, compilation

I'm making a Go program and have created a module to divide it. Here is my working tree (the `minimal` directory is in `$GOPATH/src/`):

```
  minimal/
  ├── main.go
  └── ui
      ├── go.mod
      ├── go.sum
      └── ui.go
```

In the `ui` module I have the following:

```golang
package ui

import "github.com/satori/go.uuid"

func SomeFunction() {
    id, err := uuid.NewV4()
    if err == nil {
        print(id.String())
    } else {
        print(err)
    }
}
```

The `main` package uses this module as follows

```golang
package main

import "minimal/ui"

func main() {
    ui.SomeFunction()
}
```

Here is the `go.mod` file:

```
module minimal/ui

go 1.14

require github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0
```

When running `go build` in the main package folder, everything works and the binary is generated. However, when building **only** the `ui` module, it gives the following compilation error:

```sh
ui$ go build
# minimal/ui
./ui.go:6:10: assignment mismatch: 2 variables but uuid.NewV4 returns 1 values
```

You can check https://github.com/satori/go.uuid to see that the function returns two values. What has me puzzled is that building the main package works, but the module doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: Can you paste the content of your `go.mod` file, as well?

Comment: Also note you should not use `import "minimal/ui"` -- Go [does not support relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38517593/13860).

Comment: The `github.com/satori/go.uuid` package does not appear to fully support/embrace `go modules` build. See my answer for details.

Comment: Added go.mod for completeness. I think the question is solved, thank you all for your time.

Comment: That makes sense. The `ui` build was building with `go modules` (as you have a `go.mod` there). The `minimal` build uses a GOPATH build (as no `go.mod`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[github.com/satori/go.uuid](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid) documentation appears to support `GOPATH` builds. `go module` builds, however, produce inconsistent results.

Take the simple API usage from it's [README.md](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/blob/master/README.md):

```
package main
import "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
func main() {
    u, err := uuid.NewV4()
    _, _ = u, err
}
```

And try to compile it with `go modules`:

```sh
go mod init
go build

go: finding module for package github.com/satori/go.uuid
go: found github.com/satori/go.uuid in github.com/satori/go.uuid v1.2.0

./main.go:6:9: assignment mismatch: 2 variables but uuid.NewV4 returns 1 values
```

it pulled tagged `v1.2.0` and it failed to compile.

So now pull the latest commit:

```sh
go get github.com/satori/go.uuid@master

go: github.com/satori/go.uuid master => v1.2.1-0.20181028125025-b2ce2384e17b
```

Now it compiles:

```sh
go build && echo $?
0
```

**So what is happening here?**

`github.com/satori/go.uuid` is tagged with a mature `v1` release, so all dot releases should be feature enhancements with no *breaking* changes.
The latest tagged version `v1.2.0` returns only one value from `uuid.NewV4()`.

The latest commit (which `go modules` infers a pseudo dot release version of `v1.2.1-0.20181028125025-b2ce2384e17b`) has code that matches the `README.md`.

If this repo ever becomes tagged as `v1.2.1` - this would be a breaking change, as it changes the signature of a function published in a previous `v1` release. This would be a violation of `semver` rules.

**Conclusion:**

The documentation matches a `GOPATH` (i.e. non-`go modules`) build. `GOPATH` builds always pull the latest commit.

From a `go modules` perspective, while one may be able to coerce a working build, it does not look like it's supported. Yes, the git repo uses `semver` tags, but there is no `go.mod`.

I would not trust this package with a `go modules` build. Perhaps consider using [github.com/google/uuid](https://github.com/google/uuid) which does.

Comment: I get it, so in summary `go build` does not check dependencies against the same as `go modules` right?

Comment: Not quite. `GO111MODULE=on go build` forces the old school `GOPATH` type build, which pulls the latest commits for all imports. This is the case even if you have a `go.mod` in your build directory. `go build` (with no `GO111MODULE` env var), if it finds a fresh `go.mod` will use the latest semver tagged commits for your imports - and stores these versions in `go.mod`. Future builds will continue to use these fixed versions, unless you update a package import manually.

Comment: It's not "inconsistent", it's just old. `master` is [12 commits](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/releases/tag/v1.2.0) ahead of v1.2.0. And in those changes, the function signature was changed.

Comment: @Flimzy it's just confusing from a `go modules` build perspective. It looks like its supported - with the `semver` tagging - but looking at the code trajectory - the latest commit is a breaking change.

Comment: It is supported. It's just that `master` hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @Flimzy when `master` is tagged as a release, what would be it's version? `v1.2.1`? `v1.3.0`? whatever it is, it's a breaking change for a `v1.*` type release.

Comment: @colm.anseo: You have to ask the package author. But considering it represents a changed API, if the author follows semver properly, it would be v2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `uuid` package has different versions. In the latest version, function NewV4() returns just one variable but in the previous versions, it returns two variables which one of them is an `error`.

You create a `go.mod` file in the subdirectory of your project, So when you compile your project in the main directory, go-compiler uses one version, and in your `ui` directory it uses another version to compile. You should just edit the version of `uuid` package in your `go.mod` file.