# antlr redeclared as imported package name

Tags: go

I built a directory src which contains the following:

```
src/
  antlr/
   basic_levex.go
   basic_parse.go
   basicparser_base_visitor.go
   basicparser_visitor.go
  example1.go
```

The antlr files look correct, and built the files called BasicLexer.g4 and BasicParser.g4 .

My example1.go file looks like:

```
package main

// example1.go

import (
    "./antlr"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
)

func main() {
    // Setup the input
    is := antlr.NewInputStream("1 + 2 * 3")

    // Create the Lexer
    lexer := antlr.NewBasicLexer(is)

    // Read all tokens
    for {
        t := lexer.NextToken()
        if t.GetTokenType() == antlr.TokenEOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s (%q)\n",
            lexer.SymbolicNames[t.GetTokenType()], t.GetText())
    }
}
```

The error I get on compilation is

```
# command-line-arguments
./example1.go:8:2: antlr redeclared as imported package name
    previous declaration at ./example1.go:6:2
./example1.go:16:11: undefined: "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr".NewBasicLexer
```

I don't really know what is wrong. How to fix it so it doesn't happen in the future?

Comment: The error message is pretty specific, in even telling you which two lines have the conflict. The problem is that two of your imports have the same name of `antlr`. Line 8: `"github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"` and line 6: `"./antlr"`

Comment: Also note that `"./antlr"` is not a correct import statement, because [Go does not support relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go)

Comment: 1. Use modules. 2. Never use relative imports. 3. If two packages have the same name you _must_ rename one like `import othername "import/path/of/pgk"`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at both your problems one after an other

### Duplicate Import

```
./example1.go:8:2: antlr redeclared as imported package name
    previous declaration at ./example1.go:6:2
```

The error message is explaining pretty well what happened, including the lines:
On line 8 you try to import something with the same name that you already have imported on line 6.
Aside that, [Go Does not support relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517593/relative-imports-in-go), like [Flimzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13860/flimzy) has pointed out in the comments.
To fix this remove the relative import on line 6.

### Undefined function

```
./example1.go:16:11: undefined: "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr".NewBasicLexer
```

The function that you are trying to use does not exist.

In this case it is actually called `NewBaseLexer` as opposed to `NewBasicLexer` as you can see in [the code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/62a0b02bf4608a225f803068774f1aa3881dd4a0/runtime/Go/antlr/lexer.go#L53)