# how to fix duplicate module in workspace

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am doing a exercises for creating a module and then accessing global variable through main package.
tutorial at: https://www.golinuxcloud.com/golang-access-variable-from-another-package/

```
mkdir -p goexamples/global-vars
$ cd goexamples/global-vars
$ touch main.go
$ mkdir util
$ touch util/common.go
$ go mod init global-vars
go: creating new go.mod: module global-vars
go: to add module requirements and sums: go mod tidy
$ go mod tidy
$ cat go.mod 
module global-vars
go 1.20
$ cd .. 
tree .
 .
 └── global-vars
     ├── go.mod
     ├── main.go
     └── util
      └── common.go
```

I will try to access variable from common package into main package.
Here is the content of `util/common.go`

```
package util

var Mypath string    <<< global variable

func init() {
    Mypath = "/tmp"
}
```

Content of main.go:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "global-vars/util"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("The path is: " + util.Mypath)
}
```

when I try to run:

```
PS C:\Users\Shawn\go\vsCodeExam\Study_Go\goexamples\global-vars> go run main.go
```

I'll get the error saying:

```
go: module golang.org/x/sys appears multiple times in workspace.
```

(vsCodeExam is the only workspace with both go.work & go.mod)

go.mod :

```
module golang.org/x/sys

go 1.17
```

go.work:

```
go 1.20

use (
   .
   ./DebuggingEx
   ./DebuggingEx/TestFiles
   ./DebuggingEx/go-debugging
   ./Study_Go
)
```

My GOPATH: `C:\Users\Shawn\go`

Please tell me how to fix the problem since if you remember I am fairly new to Golang.

Comment: Please run `go env` and let us know what `GOWORK=` line says (it looks like you have a workspace setup). The root cause is likely to be your [`go.mod`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-module) saying your module is `golang.org/x/sys` and you have other modules using the same path ([`golang.org/x/sys`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys) is a module published by the Go team; you should not really use the same path). Change the module path in your `go.mod` to a unique name (e.g. `github.com/DarkSideOfTheMoon/goexamples`) - also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64316294/11810946).

Comment: `go run main.go` will compile only that source file. In general you should use `go run` only for trivial, single file, programs. For all other cases `go build` (e.g., `go build ./...`).

Comment: Besides the issues pointed out by @Brits, avoid placing the module in a directory whose ancestor directories has `go.work` or `go.mod` (unless you know what it means to your module).

Comment: Never, literally _never_ use go run with filename arguments _unless_ you understand what you are doing _exactly_. Get used to `go build` your stuff and if (for whatever reason you cannot type build but only run) use at least `go run .` only.

Comment: result of go env:

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is something like the following:

You have a workspace (simplified):

```
go 1.20

use (
   ./DebuggingEx
   ./DebuggingEx/TestFiles
)
```

and in each folder a `go.mod`:

`DebuggingEx/go.mod`:

```
module golang.org/x/sys
```

`DebuggingEx/TestFiles/go.mod`:

```
module golang.org/x/sys
```

So when Go loads the workspace it retrieves the two folders and detects that you have two modules called `golang.org/x/sys` (in fact, as `golang.org/x/sys` is a real module and likely imported from the standard library, a single module with this name is likely to cause issues!).

Your first question should be "Do I need a workspace". Workspaces are great when you are working on a complicated app and editing multiple modules at the same time. However they do add some complexity and you probably don't need one (so deleting the `go.work` may be an option). Until you understand how modules work (and import path standards) using a workspace is likely to cause unnecessary confusion.

I suspect a second question should be "Do I need multiple go.mod files"? In your case I'd guess that the answer is "no". Put a single `go.mod` at the root of your folder and forget about it (well you may need to run `go mod tidy` and `go get -u ./..."` from time to time). You do not need a separate `go.mod` for each subfolder (there are occasions where this may be desirable but probably not worth worrying about now). Bear in mind that a [module is](https://go.dev/ref/mod#modules-overview) "a collection of packages that are released, versioned, and distributed together" - so all of your code while learning can quite happily live within a single module (given that you are not releasing, versioning or distributing).

Regardless of the above your module names (as used in `go mod init name` and `module name`) should be unique. They identify your module (and the fact that you might be importing `golang.org/x/sys` is irrelevant). Calling your module `golang.org/x/sys` will lead to issues because that is the name of an existing module (that will probably be needed!).

Here is a sample module (called `temp3`) that uses `golang.org/x/sys`:

```
module temp3

go 1.20

require golang.org/x/sys v0.10.0
```

It's the `require` line that declares that `golang.org/x/sys` is needed (and provides a minimum version).

Using module names like `temp3` [is valid](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-ident). However if you want to share your code it becomes an issue (someone else may well use the same name) and prevents the Go tooling from automatically getting the module (it does not know where to find `temp3`; unless you use a `go.work`). Because of this general practice is to use an import path [that can](https://go.dev/doc/code#ImportingRemote) "describe how to obtain the package source code using a revision control system such as Git or Mercurial" (e.g. `github.com/DarkSideOfTheMoon/goexamples`). You don't have to do this when working locally but it's a good habit to get into (as is using a version control system such as Git).